# Appropriate way to compare two lists and generate error message indicating any indexes where they are different with corresponding difference?

Tags: c#, list

I have two lists of doubles that I need to compare for equality. There are obviously a million ways to do this, the simplest probably being `list1.Equals(list2)`. However I want to have some sort of error message indicating precisely every list index and value for both lists wherever there is a difference. This error message would hopefully be something like

> list1 and list2 are not equal.
>
> list1 has value 0.1 at index 2, list2 has value 0.05 at index 2
>
> *etc. etc. for every difference*

I also have a Utilities method already called `AreEqual` that basically just compares the values.

My first thought was evidently to loop through the lists and use `AreEqual` (I already know the lists are the same length)

```
for (int index = 0; index < list1.Count; index++)
    {
         check.AreEqual(list1[index], list2[index]);
    }
```

but this doesn't help much for generating a useful error message unless in the case they're not equal I call some method to generate an error message like this

```
public string ErrorMessage(List<double> oldList, List<double> newList)
{
     // build some error message here by taking the list difference 
     // and using IndexOf or whatnot
}
```

This seems super overkill, though. I can think of a million ways to do this but I can't determine what an *appropriate* way to do it is.

- Is looping over the values and calling an error-message generating method reasonable?
- Or is using something like

  ```
    list3 = list1.Except(list2)
  ```

  and then checking whether or not `list3` is empty or not and correspondingly using `IndexOf` to get the differing values in both lists appropriate?
- Or am I losing my mind and there's a much more straightforward way to do this?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your idea of using a loop and an ErrorMessage() function to format the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using Linq here just makes it more complicated, when you can just do something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> DifferenceErrors(List<double> list1, List<double> list2)
{
    // I recommend defining a minimum difference below which you consider the values to be identical:
    const double EPSILON = 0.00001;

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; ++i)
        if (Math.Abs(list1[i] - list2[i]) >= EPSILON)
            yield return $"At index {i}, list1 has value {list1[i]} and list2 has value {list2[i]}";
}
```

If you want to use C# prior to C#6 change the yield to this:

```
yield return string.Format("At index {0} list1 has value {1} and list2 has value {2}", i, list1[i], list2[i]);
```

Comment: This is interesting. Noob question - using this check, how could I actually return some bool true or false as well for whether there are any differences?

Comment: @HavelTheGreat You could use `string message = string.Join("\n", DifferenceErrors(list1, list2));` and then check if `message.Length > 0` - it will be 0 if there are no differences.

Comment: @HavelTheGreat If you wanted a version that works with earlier versions of C# you just need to change the  `yield return` to string.Format(). I'll update my answer to include it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following LINQ query:

```
string sizeMsg = "";
if (list1.Count != list2.Count)
    sizeMsg = String.Format("They have a different size, list1.Count:{0} list2.Count:{1}", list1.Count, list2.Count);
int count = Math.Min(list1.Count, list2.Count);
var differences = Enumerable.Range(0, count)
    .Select(index => new { index, d1 = list1[index], d2 = list2[index] })
    .Where(x => x.d1 != x.d2)
    .Select(x => String.Format("list1 has value {0} at index {1}, list2 has value {2} at index {1}"
        , x.d1, x.index, x.d2));
string differenceMessage = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, differences);
```

Comment: I like this, thanks. I'll place something similar in a bool method for the comparison with an `out` string for the error message I think.

Answer (score 0):

for eq test I will use this and check if list3 is empty

> list3 = list1.Except(list2)

if list3 is not empty and values are unique - we can loop thru list three and provide meaning full feedback.
This seems to be the easiest for me.
but using linqPad - had a small test(6 entries are different)

```
var list1 = new List<double>{1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,11};
var list2 = new List<double>{1,2,3,5,6,7,8,19,20};

var list3 = list1.Except(list2).Dump();
var list4 = list2.Except(list1).Dump();
```

> IEnumerable (4 items)  4  9  10  11
>
> IEnumerable (4 items)  5  6  19  20

but result gives us only four entries are different.
If you care about order - there is a need for a loop, if not - go with except.